# How to get multiple search results with ruby geocoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, mapbox, rails-geocoder

is it possible, to get multiple search results using ruby geocoder gem? For example - with

```
Geocoder.search("San jose")
```

I will see only San Jose, CA

```
   {"address_components"=>
     [{"long_name"=>"San Jose", "short_name"=>"San Jose", "types"=>["locality", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Santa Clara County", "short_name"=>"Santa Clara County", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"California", "short_name"=>"CA", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}],
    "formatted_address"=>"San Jose, CA, USA",
    "geometry"=>
     {"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>37.4695381, "lng"=>-121.589154}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>37.124493, "lng"=>-122.0456719}},
      "location"=>{"lat"=>37.3382082, "lng"=>-121.8863286},
      "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>37.4695381, "lng"=>-121.589154}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>37.124493, "lng"=>-122.0456679}}},
    "place_id"=>"ChIJ9T_5iuTKj4ARe3GfygqMnbk",
    "types"=>["locality", "political"]}>]
```

but there are others - in different countries:

[image]

How can I get others?

Comment: Which geocoding service are you using?

Comment: I use google's geocoder